# Unity object not rotating to mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

So I have script which I got from Blackthornprods ranged combat youtube video since im a beginner. Im trying to get my weapon to rotate around my sphere gameobject but for some reason it doesnt rotate to where the mouse position is, but when I jump it rotates around weirdly not really to the mouse but randomly (im assuming randomly). My game is 3D and his tutorial was for 2d. I would really appreciate any attempt for a solution. Here is my code:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

}
```

The weapon is still to rotate around the Z axis.

Comment: `My game is 3D and his tutorial was for 2d` well, first of all you would need to define clearly how your 3D object should react to the 2D mouse input since currently it is not clear how exactly the expected outcome looks like.

Comment: @derHugo I want the weapon to rotate around the the player using the z rotation. Not really sure if that makes sense but..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Camera.main` calls `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, which is an expensive operation, so ([as the documentation says](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)), you should call it as few times as possible and cache the result:

```
Camera mainCam;

void Awake()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}
```

Second, you're using `ScreenToWorldPoint` incorrectly. If this is really a 3d game as the question describes, you should provide a depth from the camera as the z component of the argument. You can use vector math to do this, and the result is a world position you can tread the cursor as being at.:

```
Camera mainCam;

void Awake()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    float objectDepthFromCamera = Vector3.Dot(
            transform.position - mainCam.transform.position, 
            mainCam.transform.forward); 

    Vector3 cursorWorldPosition = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition 
            + Vector3.forward * objectDepthFromCamera);
```

Then assuming the "front" of the object points out of the local up direction, you can use the optional second parameter of `Quaternion.SetRotation` to set the rotation so that is pointing toward the cursor:

```
Camera mainCam;

void Awake()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    float objectDepthFromCamera = Vector3.Dot(
            transform.position - mainCam.transform.position, 
            mainCam.transform.forward); 

    Vector3 cursorWorldPosition = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition 
            + Vector3.forward * objectDepthFromCamera);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward,
            cursorWorldPosition - transform.position);
}
```

If the front of the object points out the local right direction, you can use `Vector3.Cross` to determine what direction the local up should be pointing:

```
Camera mainCam;

void Awake()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    float objectDepthFromCamera = Vector3.Dot(
            transform.position - mainCam.transform.position, 
            mainCam.transform.forward); 

    Vector3 cursorWorldPosition = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition 
            + Vector3.forward * objectDepthFromCamera);

    Vector3 localUpNeeded = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.forward, 
            cursorWorldPosition - transform.position);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, localUpNeeded);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying quickly. I implemented the code into my script and the weapon is rotating incorrectly on the player. I think I might have explained incorrectly but I want the weapon the rotate only around the z axis. Apologies for that. I also failed to understand what vector3.dot does, I tried to put a z value but it gave me errors says that dot takes 3 arguments. Maybe this is a really simple fix but I only started around 2 months ago so...

Comment: @Moodie what color arrow points out of the front of the object?

Comment: @Moodie Also, [`Vector3.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) takes exactly 2 arguments, so I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @Moodie I edited my question to address two possibilities that your question is vague about. Hopefully one of them applies to your situation. From looking at the math in the question, I infer that the latter might help you more.

Comment: If I go on the rotate tool I want to rotate around the blue circle. Think of it like a top down shooter but I made it 3d, kinda like brackeys ball wars game.

Comment: @Moodie Thanks, but you have already explained that you intend to rotate around the z axis. What arrow points out of (or away from) the front of your object? Your question does not mention what local side of the object should be the one facing the cursor. The only thing I know is that it's not the local forward or back sides.

Comment: @Moodie Let me illustrate. Not your question nor your comments have yet explained if either of [these pictures](https://i.imgur.com/ILrdIoX.png) are more accurate, or if there is some other orientation of your object.  This is information that should have been included in the question.

Comment: @Moodie I edited my answer to use `Quaternion.LookRotation` instead of `transform.LookAt`, which didn't make any sense after the previous change. Hopefully that fixes the problem.

Comment: ah yes thanks so much it now works, been trying figure it out for some time and now it works. Thanks!!